# Snap creating a symlink to home folders? Is there a way to turn off these links?

Tags: 20.04, snap, symbolic-link

So, Snap has a 'snap' folder in my Home Directory, with more folders for the Snap apps I've installed, from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

One thing that I've noticed is that one of those apps, Inkscape, has some numbered sub folders, and in those sub folders are links to most of my main Home folders. (Downloads, Desktop, Music, Pictures, Templates, etc) And then those links lead to files that LOOK like they're duplicates of my home folders.

As far as I can tell, they are symlinks because my Downloads folder is massive and I would notice in my disk analysis if I had two of them.

But when I go to the files and look at their info (in the GUI) it says their file location is where it says it is, deep in the snap / Inkscape folder.

Also, if I'm searching for something on my machine using Catfish, it will find the file twice. First in Downloads, and then in the snap directory tree that also has Downloads. (If that makes sense.)

So far, it's Inkscape as the only app that has done this.

I'm wondering if this is a Snap feature that can be turned off? Is there a reason it's only Inkscape doing it?

[image: An example of the error]

Comment: I cannot find such linked folders under `snap\inkscape`. The access to Downloads etc. is provided by the home interface. A snap does not create symlinks to achieve access, and anyway, that would not work if the interface is not enabled. So I guess it would be safe for you to delete these links on your system if any.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it happens to everybody evenly. I have seen some other people talking about other similar issues with other apps, though. The thing that worries me is that the files deeper in those links show their location within the snap tree and not just pointing back to where it's original was.

Is that a behaviour of symlinked folders?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. For me, Inkscape installed though snap does not create such symlinks. Ubuntu 20.04, Inkscape 1.0.1 (3bc2e813f5, 2020-09-07). Your "current" symlink is broken: that is automatically created and should point to one of the numbered folders. I suggest you delete the entire snap/inkskape folder to start again with factory defaults.

Comment: This worked! I removed the Inkscape snap. I'm downloading it in it's non-snap format just to avoid the possible issue again, but that took care of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer was to remove the Inkscape snap entirely, via the Software Centre. I did not try re-installing Inkscape through Snap to test if the same Home Directory symlinked folders would come back.

(I did install the 'regular' Inkscape that comes from the Ubuntu repositories.)

If this occurs to you (and it may not be caused by Inkscape, but instead by Snap's methods,) uninstalling the app where the Home Directory symlinks are formed may be your only solution!